# Symfony 3.2 PHP Error not displayed

Tags: symfony

I have an almost fresh install of Symfony 3.2 and it appears not to be capturing and displaying PHP errors.

To test, I have omitted the final semicolon from a line in a working controller. When I try to access the route a blank screen is displayed (the app returns nothing). This is in the dev environment. The error is logged by Symfony, but it is not handled and displayed by the debug component. This is my first version 3 project - I have previously worked in version 2 where the nicely formatted error would be returned for such an error.

Any ideas how to fix this?

I am on PHP version 5.5.9.

The relevant lines in the Symfony log are:

php.CRITICAL: Fatal Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN) {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException(code: 0): Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN) at /var/www/html/tcfdev/src/AppBundle/Controller/HomeController.php:17)"} []

and

request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: "Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN)" at /var/www/html/tcfdev/src/AppBundle/Controller/HomeController.php line 17 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException(code: 0): Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN) at /var/www/html/tcfdev/src/AppBundle/Controller/HomeController.php:17)"} []

The apache2 log contains the following:

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN) in /var/www/html/tcfdev/src/AppBundle/Controller/HomeController.php on line 17

So it appears that debug is picking it up but failing to display it.

Comment: Do you open the page with /app_dev.php ?

Comment: can you show us the error that symfony is actually logging? and are you able to check the server logs to check whats there?  Also, are you using PHP7?

Comment: To Miracle Johnson - yes opening with app_dev.php. If I open with app I get a 404 error. With app_dev I get an empty response error.

Comment: To @DevDonkey - I have added the reply to the body of the query above. Using PHP 5.5.9.

Answer (score 0):

An almost fresh install? Did you get this from another project? Does your routing_dev.yml have the profiler and errors setup?

It should look something like this:

```
_wdt:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml"
    prefix:   /_wdt

_profiler:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"
    prefix:   /_profiler

_errors:
    resource: "@TwigBundle/Resources/config/routing/errors.xml"
    prefix:   /_error

_main:
    resource: routing.yml
```

Comment: Yes - it looks exactly like that.